# Make field appear using CSS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I just want to create a field which will appear if the user clicks on a button. I know that would also work with just a simple target in CSS, but in my use, I need to do this in the way I tried it. I know it's very much CSS, but I think it shouldn't be too hard to check.

Here is my try:

```js
function brief() {
  $('.envelope-wrapper').toggleClass('animate');
}
```

```css
.envelope-wrapper {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 735px;
  height: 440px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -367px;
  top: 300px;
  margin-top: -220px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  overflow: visible;
  background: #008da9;
}
.envelope-wrapper.animate {
  -webkit-animation-name: visible;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-direction: forward;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
}
@-webkit-keyframes visible {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 10;
  }
  90% {
    opacity: 10;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="brief()" class="gogogo">go</div>
<div class="envelope-wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: It looks like your code should work. What's wrong with it?

Comment: if i run it in jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/9xrdqvf4/7/) it doesn't :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might because the `envelope-wrapper` seems to be forming a overlay on top of the `gogogo` element which would not fire a click event.

Set `position:relative` for both the elements.

```
.gogogo {
    position: relative;
}

.envelope-wrapper {
    position: relative;
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/7uy3evd0/)**

Also opacity values varies between `0` and `1`

```
@-webkit-keyframes visible {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    10 {
        opacity: 0.1;
    }
    90% {
        opacity: 0.9;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```

**[Check Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/7uy3evd0/2/)**

Comment: but in your edit there isn't a transition between the opacity Keyframes

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use jQuery .fadeToggle() 
http://api.jquery.com/fadetoggle/

Comment: Alternative. Just run an on click event. (also event-wrapper was covering the button, prevent from a click to be detected. Easier to spot if its styled slightly. pointer-event:none; gets around that.

https://jsfiddle.net/9xrdqvf4/12/